# unknown error/data in LIKE query Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code

```
$opslaglimit = 5;

$fag = "dansk";         
$fagquery = "%".ucfirst($fag)."%";
$fagopslag = $db->prepare("
    SELECT 
            *, 
            teacher_opslag.id as mainid, 
            teacher_opslag.created AS opslagcreated, 
            teacher_opslag.subject AS opslagsubject, 
            teacher_opslag.deleted AS maindeleted 
    FROM 
            teacher_opslag 
    WHERE 
            teacher_opslag.subject LIKE ? 
    ORDER BY 
            teacher_opslag.id DESC 
    LIMIT 
            $opslaglimit
"); 
$fagopslag->bind_param("s", $fagquery);
$fagopslag->execute(); 
$fagresult = $fagopslag->get_result(); 
$ensuranced = $fagresult->num_rows;
```

The query should select all data where `dansk` is present from the table. one of my rows might look like this `Dansk_Engelsk_Svensk`. The num_rows returns 0.

It is the first time i use `LIKE` in a `WHERE` clause. I dont know why it returns 0 when i have 3 matching rows in the db.

please help, thanks

Comment: Have you tried running this query in MySQL Workbench, or PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Also, what column are you seeing `Dansk_Engelsk_Svensk` in? Your query only looks in the `subject` column.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks! i forgot i have encrypted my db

Comment: That's a strange thing to forget :)